# When testing a file for readability using stat() do I need to test S_IRUSR, S_IRGRP & S_IROTH?

Tags: c, file, posix, stat

I'm writing a program using `stat` to look at file attributes. When testing to see if a file is readable, do I need to test all three modes `S_IRUSR`, `S_IRGRP` & `S_IROTH` or is there a single test for all 3 that I could perform on the `stat.st_mode` then?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on exactly what "readable" means.  S_IRUSR tells if the file is readable by the owner.  S_IRGRP tells if the file is readby by the group.  And S_IROTH tells if the file is readable to all others.

Note that ACLs are excluded from these, but ACLs are not too commonly used.

In order to determine if the running process can read the file, the best bet is to just go ahead and open the file for reading and check it is succeeds.

Comment: The program I'm writing isn't going to open any files. Do the test `S_IROTH` test exclusively `read others` or do `read group` and `read owner` also fall into it?

Comment: All three bits are completely separate.  A process uses one of the three like this: if the user matches, the S_IRUSR bit applies; otherwise if the group matches, the S_IRGRP bit applies.  Finally, if neither of those apply, S_IROTH applies.  Ignoring ACLs.

Comment: Ok, that is what I wanted to know for the purpose of this test. So I do have to test all three then.